# JQuery combobox dropdown menu position

Tags: jquery, combobox

JQuery autocomplete widget by default appends dropdown menu to body tag (**appendTo** option). I try to use the same option for combobox but this is not working. I there any solution to append combobox to some div element?

Comment: Any code? Even the non working code?

Comment: Please close this topic. I'm sorry for the mess.